# wkhtmltopdf: Printer doesn't print greyscale

Tags: pdf, printing, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I can export my hmtl and css perfectly to a pdf and it looks just like it should on screen. When I print the pdf though a lot of greyscales don't get printed at all or for example table boarders are very very faint.

Before someone asks: Yes I have checked the printer and it prints other pdfs perfectly. So it has to do with the encoding. Whats weired is, that it looks fine on screen, but not when it is printed.

Is ther anything I could maybe add to the export or change in my style sheet?

```
wkhtmltopdf --margin-right 0 --margin-top 10  http://localhost:8000/invoice_de invoice_de.pdf
```

Html and CSS: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYEzgp

Link to pdf: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uohahdvchj6u9ni/invoice_de.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Do you have an example of the PDF you're attempting to print as well? That'll probably tell more. Two remarks already though - 1) There's a big difference between visible on screen and printable, especially with greyspace. And that's typically even dependent on the printer. 2) Especially for your table borders, if you specify border size with pixels or points, you might run into the same problem. A printer can print many more pixels per inch than your screen, hence why borders tend to appear more faintly on high resolution printers.

Comment: I have added a link to the pdf

Comment: What makes you think this PDF *should* print correctly? You have a design that is very, very light, the lines you use in your tables come out as 0.27mm which is not a lot and they're drawn in a very light RGB color. These lines will likely appear wider on screen because of how PDF drawing works, but on a high resolution device I doubt they're ever going to be anything more than faint. Now, it would be better if they were defined as actual grayscale (and not RGB) and you'll probably just need to make them wider and more gray if you want them to be more prominent...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. This screen/printer difference is pretty annoying, because what looks nice on screen doesn't look good in print and vice versa. It's a bit of trial and error and a lot of print outs..

One basically needs to different style sheets, one for screen and one for the pdf conversion.